# Can I find who is the owner of a mobile with the wifi address?

Tags: wifi-configuration, ip-address

I have a screenshot of a message that just has the carrier and the wifi address (Mac OS). Can I possibly find who is the owner with just that detail?

Comment: I suspect that you would have to ask the carrier, and they would say not without a court order.

Comment: The MAC address is not broadcast over the internet nor is is "assigned" to people specifically. Carriers can use it as part of their provisioning of IP addresses, but you won't have access to that information. As a user the only thing the MAC address tells you is the [manufacturer or vendor of the network device](https://macvendors.com/).